# How to solve overlapping shadow issue?

Tags: sketch-app, interface-design, shadows, drop-shadow

In a UI with multiple cards arranged in a grid, the shadow of cards are falling on top of other cards. All these cards are supposed to be on the same level (elevation/depth). Is there any way to solve this issue in Sketch without merging these shapes into a single layer?

[image: Overlapping card shadows]

Comment: You could merely change the stacking order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the cards and apply the shadow to the group instead of the individual cards. This way you don't have to merge all the shapes.

Bonus: your layers will be more organised, and you'll be sure that all cards have the same settings for the shadows.

Comment: But if you do that, won't the shadow be applied to the group instead? Then you lose the ability to create a smooth effect for every card in your group right? Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: @Clafou the shadow is applied to every card in the group and the shadows won't overlap, what do you mean? What smooth effect?

Comment: I just though it wouldn't work that way, sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Comment: There are some limitations for this method.
1. Sketch won't allow to add more than one shadow to a group. But this can be overcome by wrapping the group in another group.
2. When I handover the designs to devs through Zeplin, this shadows won't show up. There is no way devs can see the specs of the group shadows. This is a bummer.

Comment: @Dreamist yeah, the real solution is to make those shadows shorter, since the cards are so close to each other the softness effect gets lost, the shadows get quite dark anyway.